# Encountered conflicts when cherry-picking commit . This operation needs to be performed locally error in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request, cherry-pick

I need to merge changes from one branch (this branch originated from the `demo` branch) let's say `feature1FromDemo` to another branch (`beta`).

There is a difference in the source code of the `beta` and `demo` branches, So I cannot raise a PR directly from `feature1FromDemo` to `beta` because it shows other changes as well.

So to merge only my changes I have thought to create PR only for my changes and cherry-pick that to the `beta` branch. So I have created a temporary branch from `demo` named `feature1FromDemoTemp` and raised PR to merge `feature1FromDemo` to `feature1FromDemoTemp` and then cherry-picked the changes.

It is giving the error .

> Encountered conflicts when cherry-picking commit "00373b". This
> operation needs to be performed locally.

[image]

I have tried to cherry-pick this particular commit as well but still gives the same error.

So how to merge the changes I have made in`feature1FromDemo` the `beta` branch?

Comment: Thanks for the background info. It all sounds perfectly reasonable and normal. What's the question?

Comment: @matt So how to merge the changes I have made in `feature1FromDemo` to the `beta` branch?

Comment: Well personally I do not at all see what feature1FromDemoTemp is for. But in any case, merge conflicts in this situation are not surprising. I would do what the message says: perform the operation locally and resolve the conflicts.

Comment: @matt so it means in the local system not directly on the Azure DevOps portal?

Comment: Yes. Local means local.

Comment: Hi vivek, is your issue resolved? Has my post helped with your issue?

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT I will verify and update, sorry was just moved to different things

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT sorry I have not got a chance to work on it. whenever I try this I will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we suppose the only way is to edit your beta branch directly with the changes (on cloud or clone to local and modify).

But I suppose that in your scenario you would need to avoid [multiple merge base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging-with-squash?view=azure-devops#multiple-merge-bases) issue.

One method is that you keep your merges among multiple branches on one-way, like `demo->beta->master`, or `master->beta->demo`.

If cross-base could hardly be avoided in your developing, you could switch your merge type to `Rebase and Fast-Forward`.

[image]

I have `dev` and `test` branched from `main`.
[image]

After my merges from `dev` to `test` and `dev` to `main` with `rebase and fast forward`, the commit ids for the branches are still the same.
[image]